# How to remove a subview from tabbarcontroller view

Tags: ios, swift, view

Ok, so currently I have hit a minor problem that I would like to fix. Ok, so I have two view controllers vc1 and vc2 embedded in a tab bar controller. Now I have in the app delegate for the initial selected item to be 0 or vc1. I then add a small orange dot onto the tab bar controller tab bar with the function addDot() in the viewDidLoad of vc1. Now all I want to do is have when the user clicks on vc2 or tab bar controller item 1, it removes the orange dot added in vc1. I have a function called remove dot in vc1 that I call in vc2, but nothing happens. Here is some of my code:

```
 class vc1: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
addDot()
}
let dot = UIView()
func addDot() {

    dot.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 97.5, y: self.view.frame.height - 9.5, width: 7, height: 7)
    dot.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.949, green: 0.251, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    dot.layer.cornerRadius = 3.5
    dot.clipsToBounds = true
    tabBarController?.view.addSubview(dot)
}
func removerDot () {

    dot.removeFromSuperview()
    dot.isHidden = true
     self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].title = "Discover"

}
}
```

and vc2 (tab bar item 1)

```
  class vc2: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let vc1 = vc1()
   vc1.removeDot()
}

}
```

So basically all I want to do is add a dot to the tabbarcontroller tab bar and if it is the selected item of 1, remove the dot. I have tried to figure it out, but I cannot, please put your opinion bc it probably is not that difficult of a problem to solve. Thanks.

Comment: The line `let vc1 = vc1()` is creating a new instance of vc1 it is not referring to the original one that created the dot.  You should really add the dot and all it's control to the tab bar (or a subclass of it).

Comment: subclass it as a tabbarcontroller?

Comment: Create your own subclass of UITabBarController and use that to control the dot.

Comment: and how would I call the remove function in the vc2?

Comment: Hang on I'm just knocking up some test code and will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all within a subclass of the UITabBarController like this:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    let dot = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup the initial attributes of the dot here.
        dot.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 7, height: 7)
        dot.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.949, green: 0.251, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
        dot.layer.cornerRadius = 3.5
        dot.clipsToBounds = true
        self.view.addSubview(dot)
    }

    override var selectedViewController: UIViewController? {
        get {
            return super.selectedViewController
        }
        set {
            super.selectedViewController = newValue
            // Determine which controller has been selected and adjust the dot accordingly.
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to determine where to place the code when the selected view controller changes but you get the basics.

Now having said that this is probably not the best way of doing it overall as you are going to have to fool around with the frames manually, etc.  If you can you are better off having separate images for unselected and selected states with the dot already in them or you can try to change the text label instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Upholder said in their comment, your code `let vc1 = vc1()` is creating a brand new instance of `vc1` that has nothing to do with your tab bar controller. That's like buying a new car, setting the station on the radio in the new car, and then wondering why the station in your existing car isn't set to the new station.

You need a way to get a pointer in vc2 that points to vc1.

Assuming you set up your tab bar controller and it's child view controllers in a Storyboard, the tab bar controller's `prepare(for:sender:)` method will be called as each child view controller is loaded. You can use `prepare(for:sender:)` to set up links between the two view controllers.

Alternately, you could use the notification center to broadcast a notification when the user taps on the orange dot, and listen for that notification in the other view controller.

By the way, class names should start with upper-case letters, so `vc1` should be `Vc1` or better yet `VC1` (since VC stands for ViewController) and `vc2` should be `VC2`.

Comment: thanks, the classes are named differently, I just used this as an example.